# Is there a Directory of 3rd Party Components for FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-xe2, firemonkey

In order to migrate my VCL project to FireMonkey, I'll have to replace several 3rd party components. In particular, I'm looking at replacing a WYSIWYG editor, an AdvancedGrid, a TreeView and an Office Ribbon.

Are there any directories available listing the 3rd party FireMonkey components available or in development?

Comment: Are there such things for vcl components? Would you trust them to be comprehensive?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Torry's used to be my go-to site. I stopped several years ago, thought. Nowadays I lean more towards commercial 3rd party components.

Comment: In the very old days there was Delphi Super Page, then more recently (but still really only up to date for 10 years ago) Torry's.  There is now now reasonably up to date page listing all delphi components for VCL, let alone FMX.  Perhaps a Wiki would be a more modern replacement to non-wiki website.

Comment: I suggest you go [start a wiki](http://www.wikia.com/Special:CreateNewWiki?uselang=en).

Comment: I created a wiki not so long ago at DelphiWiki.com. You're welcome to register.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I maintain a list of available third party FireMonkey components at [The TIndex](http://www.tindex.net/FireMonkey/ThirdParty.html).

It's not a very long list at present. If I've missed any let me know at [The TIndex Blog](http://blog.tindex.net)

Comment: Excellent. I'll send you any 3rd Party FireMonkey news I hear about. Thanks for making this available.

Comment: This index hasn't been updated in a while.  It doesn't include the Apesuite components for example. ;)

Comment: The format isn't great I grant you but ApeSuite was added about 4 days ago. ;-)